# Is there any way for automatic code manipulation for a big number of classes or structs in c++?

Tags: c++, code-generation

There are a lot of `class`es and `struct`s in my code. And I would like to be able to manipulate those in an automated manner. The code manipulation of the `struct foo1` into `struct foo2` looks like this:

Unmodified `struct foo1`:

```
struct foo1 {
  int i = 3;
  bool b = true;
  std::string str = "Hi";
  char c = 'c';
};
```

Modified `struct foo2`:

```
struct foo2 {
  int i = 3;
  bool b = true;
  std::string str = "Hi";
  char c = 'c';

  std::tuple<int*,bool*,std::string*,char*> members = std::make_tuple(&i, &b, &str, &c); 
};
```

I am looking for an automated way to make the `class`es and `struct`s "smarter" with the `tuple` named members. This code manipulation should be possible in an automated manner. Any ideas how to achieve this?

## Edit 1:

The `tuple` named members needs to be updated every time an object of type `foo2` is copied or moved. That makes the code manipulation even more complicated.

## Edit 2:

Thanks goes to [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) for pointing out that members should be a member **function**:

```
static constexpr std::tuple<int foo2::*, bool foo2::*, std::string foo2::*, char foo2::*> members() { return std::make_tuple(&foo2::i, &foo2::b, &foo2::str, &foo2::c); }
```

Comment: `foo2` is buggy. Moving and copying objects of type `foo2` leaves `members` in an invalid state.

Comment: When you say you want to make the `class`es and `struct`s "smarter", what do you mean?

Comment: @Peter I want to be able to reach every member of the class by using for example `std::for_each`.

Comment: @BlueTune `std::for_each` doesn't work with tuples. Neither do all standard algorithms working with iterators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345033/is-there-any-reason-why-there-is-no-stditerator-for-stdtuple-in-c/61345083#61345083

Comment: Ok, you are right. I want to use `boost::fusion::for_each` on a tuple.

Comment: Looks like `foo2` should inherit from `foo1`, since they have members in common.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP is looking for a way to transform `foo1` to `foo2`, thats why they look so similar

Comment: @bolov Thanks for pointing that out. So the `tuple` named members needs to be updated every time the object is moved or copied. I made an edit to my post.

Comment: If this is for reflection-like features, maybe a `static constexpr std::tuple<int foo2::*, bool foo2::*, std::string foo2::*, char foo2::*> members() { return std::make_tuple(&foo2::i, &foo2::b, &foo2::str, &foo2::c); }` would do. Avoids the move and copy issues, and doesn't use per-object memory.

Comment: @BlueTune STL iterators generally assume every element in a set has the same type (or at least the same base-type for pointers). For per-member actions of different types you'll want code-generation instead of an iterator. This is probably doable with variadic templates (where iteration is usually performed with a recursive template that pops a template-argument on each iteration). Have fun! (Alternatively, if you're using only Visual Studio or MSBuild you could also use T4)

Comment: I don't know a simple way to do this. LLVM certainly has the power, but I've never tried getting a custom executable to use an appropriate LLVM library.

Comment: Alternatively, a possibility would be to have a single `tuple` member and function like `int I&()` to return the data.

Comment: Hopefully C++ 23 would have that...